# Remove Local User Profiles (Cleanly) over 7 days

Tags: powershell, profile

Goal - To run this script on a Task Schedule at 00:30 daily, remove local user profiles over 7 days cleanly (Windows 8.1 won't just let you delete the user folder). Preserve local user profiles under 7 days.

Currently the script I have just seems to delete all profiles once run.

I have tried playing with `-gt` and `-lt` but am confusing myself into double negatives etc!

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where {
    (!$_.Special) -and
    ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(7))
} | Remove-WmiObject
```

Expected result - local user profiles over 7 days deleted. Less than 7 days preserved.

Actual - Removes all local user profiles on that machine.

Comment: _under 7 days_ means older than 7 days? Shouldn't you use `-lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)` then?

Comment: There's a group policy that does it, or shared pc mode.

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to do the selection. it uses a more intuitive way to test for age ... folks *often* get the `-gt`/`-lt` test reversed with dates, so i used `age in days` for the testing. also, the CIM-* cmdlets return `datetime` objects instead of the `filetime` objects that the WMI-* cmdlets give you.

```
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$MaxDaysOld = 7

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile |
    Where-Object {
        -not $_.Special -and
        ($Today - $_.LastUseTime).Days -gt $MaxDaysOld
        }
```

you can pipe that to `Remove-CimInstance` to remove the indicated profile. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you I shall give it ago in the morning

Comment: So I ran the script and seems to be running as it should. Many thanks for your help  :)

Comment: @Dez - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]